# Laravel internal links

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for some code example which make keyword from post into internal link.

In post table I have body attribute where is text of post. And I make extra table "keyword" where is word and URL attributes.

So i need script which will automatically recognize word which is adding in table "keywords" and found this word in post text and turn this word to hyperlink. Can you guys help me, please?

```
use App\Post;
use App\Category;
use App\Keyword;


public function getSingle($slug) {
    // fetch from the DB based on slug
    $categoriesall = Category::all();
    $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    // return the view and pass in the post object
    return view('news.single')->withPost($post)->withCategoriesall($categoriesall);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a starting point for whatever you are building

```
public function getSingle($slug) {
    $keywords = Keyword::get()->toArray();
    $categoriesall = Category::all();
    $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    $post->text = $this->transform($keywords, $post->text);
    return view('news.single', compact('post', 'categoriesall'));
}

private function transform($keywords, $text)
{
     //takes 2 parameters
     //1st parameter is keywords array
     //2nd parameter is text to be transformed

     $words = explode(" ", $text); //split wherever we have space 

     foreach( $words as $key => $value ) {
         if ( in_array($value, $keywords) ) {
             $words[$key] = "<a href="/search?keywords=" . $value . ">. $value .</a>";
         }
     }

     $paragraph = implode(" ", $words);
     return $paragraph;
}
```

Keep in mind, this is a starting point as this solution is not optimized at all. e.g: if your text contains html tags, those tags might be converted as anchors because this algorithm uses space as a delimiter; and most of the time there are spaces in html.